# How to fix Homebrew in High Sierra?

Tags: homebrew, macos-high-sierra

Couldn't find a question specifically dealing with this problem in OS X High Sierra. As I still struggle to find a solution that works for me I think it is a good idea to separate old answers from new ones.

So, the problem:

```
$brew install wget                                                                      
Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
Check you have permission to write to /usr/local
```

I tried:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

But this leaves me with the same error.